# Concurrency: how to share a cache-hash safely?

Tags: concurrency, shared-memory, raku

Is it enough to protect the write accesses or is it necessary to protect the read accesses as well in `print-columns`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

my @w_list_items;
len_items_list( <car tree house mouse dog mountain snow roof> );
@w_list_items.say;

sub len_items_list ( @list ) {
   my Int $threads = Kernel.cpu-cores;
   while $threads > @list.elems {
       last if $threads < 2;
       $threads = $threads div 2;
   }

   my Int $size = @list.elems div $threads;
   my Array @portions = ( ^$threads ).map: { [ $size * $_, $size * ( $_ + 1 ) ] };
   @portions[*-1][1] = @list.elems;

   my Promise @promise;
   for @portions -> $range {
       my Int %cache;
       @promise.push: start {
           do for $range[0] ..^ $range[1] -> $i {
               my $len = print-columns( @list[$i], %cache );
               $i, $len;
           }
       };
   }

   @w_list_items = ();
   for await @promise -> @portion {
       for @portion {
           @w_list_items[.[0]] := .[1];
       }
   }
}

sub print-columns( $str, %cache? ) returns Int {
   my Int $width = 0;
   for $str.Str.NFC {
       if %cache.EXISTS-KEY( $_ ) {
           $width = $width + %cache.AT-KEY( $_ );
       }
       else {
           $width = $width + %cache.BIND-KEY( $_, char_width( $_ ) );
       }
   }
   $width;
}

sub char_width ( $cp ) {
   # dummy code:
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, main issue here is that the list is too small to get something meaningful out of the parallelization. It will probably be more expensive that it's worth. Second, if you're processing a list it's best to look at the `hyper` parameters, which do exactly that, work with list. But third and most important, it's best to not share any kind of things between the threads; you're sharing the `%cache`. If you need to share information, it's best to set up channels and do the parallel work through stateless functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the hash can be written to - as is the case here - then reads must also be protected.

Considering the concrete situation in the example, there are a few ways forward I might consider (and choose depending on the trade-offs I prefer).

#### Cache per thread

If the cache is not expected to grow very large (in terms of numbers of keys
and size of calculated values), I'd probably let each thread build its own local cache. This means there are no synchronization costs between the threads, and so they won't block on each other at all. The trade-off is more memory usage, and thus more pressure on the CPU caches.

It's an easy change; just move the declaration in one scope:

```
       @promise.push: start {
           my Int %cache;
           do for $range[0] ..^ $range[1] -> $i {
               my $len = print-columns( @list[$i], %cache );
               $i, $len;
           }
       };
```

It's easy to reason about the correctness of this approach, since there's no sharing!

#### Protect access to the hash

Use the `OO::Monitors` module to encapsulate the cache functionality in a class that acquires a lock automatically around each of its method calls:

```
use OO::Monitors;

monitor Cache {
    has Int %!cache{Int};

    method lookup(Int $key --> Int) {
        %!cache{$key}
    }

    method add(Int $key, Int $count --> Nil) {
        %!cache{$key} := $count;
    }
}
```

Make an instance of it:

```
       my Cache $cache .= new;
       @promise.push: start {
           do for $range[0] ..^ $range[1] -> $i {
               my $len = print-columns( @list[$i], $cache );
               $i, $len;
           }
       };
```

And use it:

```
sub print-columns( $str, $cache ) returns Int {
   my Int $width = 0;
   for $str.Str.NFC -> $char {
       my $char-width;
       with $cache.lookup($char) {
           $char-width = $_;
       }
       else {
           $char-width = char_width($char);
           $cache.add($char, $char-width)
       }
       $width += $char-width;
   }
   $width;
}
```

This lacks the extra memory cost of the cache-per-thread approach, but replaces the cost with lock acquisition and release.

`OO::Monitors` is a structured way to use a [`Lock`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Lock) - it uses `Lock` in its implementation. You could also fashion a solution here using `Lock` directly, at the cost of it being harder to reason about.

#### Use an immutable Map and copy it on additions to the cache

Another approach, when cache additions are quite rare in relation to lookups and the cache size is not likely to become really large, is to use an immutable `Map` and, whenever the cache gets an addition, to make a new one with the added entry. The immutability means that no locks are needed for reads.

With the caching functionality encapsulated as in the previous approach, it can be tried by replacing the `Cache` `monitor` with a `class` like this:

```
class Cache {
    has $!current-cache = Map.new;

    method lookup(Int $key --> Int) {
        $!current-cache{$key}
    }

    method add(Int $key, Int $count --> Nil) {
        my $current = $!current-cache;
        unless $current{$key}:exists { # Another thread won
            $!current-cache = Map.new( (|$current, $key => $count) );
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this implies more copying, but the win is that once the cache content stabilizes, then it's the same memory being shared - without any lock contention - over all the threads (and so CPU cores) doing the work. One could even prime the cache with, say, the ASCII range up front.

Note that what is above is *not* a generally safe way to have a concurrency-safe copying-based hash; at the very least it's vulnerable to lost updates (but since it's a cache, that doesn't matter).

#### Use a lock-free hash

Unfortunately, nobody has yet implemented a lock-free hash data structure in Raku, but that would be an ideal thing to use in this situation. I've done `Concurrent::Stack` (lock-free stack, about the easiest lock-free data structure), `Concurrent::Trie` (lock-free trie, also quite easy), and `Concurrent::Queue` (already hard enough I picked a solution from the literature). There's papers out there on lock free hashes, but they're not a walk in the park to implement!